# lwc: sfdx unable to retrieve lwc files

Tags: lightning, developer, lightning-web-components

I am currently working in a dev org and I have installed the LWC e-bike component (https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/orderBuilder)

When I create the sfdx project and retrieve the metadata the folder for LWC is empty.

If I create a new LWC through sfdx, it is created without a problem, however, I notice that it is not like lightnining components, were if you manually delete a file you can right click in the folder and hit retrieve and the files appears again.

Is there a trick to be able to retrieve these metadata?

I have added the below into the manifest, as that is what the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm) says that represent the Lightning web component bundle

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
</types>
```

But it doesnt do a thing

EDIT
This is my current version when i run

```
sfdx plugins --core
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the CLI ? If you run "sfdx plugins --core", what versions are you using ?

Comment: @FabienTaillon I have added an image with the result of running "sfdx plugins --core", I am pretty sure I am running the latest one

Comment: Can you try to uninstall the pre-release (sfdx plugins:uninstall salesforcedx) ? Since yesterday LWC is part of the core sfdx CLI, maybe you'll need to run sfdx update but the pre-release isn't needed anymore. Also, are you on Windows ? There is an ongoing bug currently: https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1023

Answer (score 9):

You can even use :

```
$ sfdx force:source:retrieve -m LightningComponentBundle
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

[There is ongoing bug](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1023) which is promised to be fixed on the 21 Feb 2019.

Meanwhile you can use the following workaround.

Create `package.xml` file with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types> 
    <version>45.0</version>
</Package>
```

for example, in `force-app` folder.

Then create file `retrieve.bat` in the same `force-app` folder with the following content.

```
call sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -w 5000 -k package.xml -r . 
unzip unpackaged.zip
del unpackaged.zip
rem move unpackaged/lwc/* main/default/lwc
mv unpackaged/lwc/* main/default/lwc
rd /s/q unpackaged
```

Then close your VS Code and open `force-app` folder in Git Bash terminal and execute there

```
./retrieve.bat
```

And the missed LWC files will be restored.

See this in action:
[image: See this in action]

Answer (score 1):

You can use cli command for all the LWC components:

```
$ sfdx force:source:retrieve -m LightningComponentBundle
```

To retrieve any specific LWC component:

```
$ sfdx force:source:retrieve -m LightningComponentBundle:<componentName>
```

More details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm)